# How does Object#respond_to? work?

Tags: ruby

See this class definition:

```
class T
  def respond_to?(name)
    name.to_s == 't' || super
  end

  def t; p 't'; end
  def t2; p 't2'; end
end
```

When I call

```
T.new.respond_to? :t2
```

It seems that it would return false, because either it equals to 't', nor does it respond to T's super class, which is Object. However, it returns true. So can anybody explain how this works?

Update:
  I realize what I thought before was wrong.

```
class P
  def t; self.class; end
end

class C < P
  def t
    p self.class
    p super
  end
end
```

When I call
    C.new.t

I'd expect the result to be:

```
C
P
```

However, I got:

```
C
C
```

So return to the respond_to? issue, when I call super, it runs Object#respond_to?, but still in the context/scope of C, so it returns true.

Comment: super runs in the context of the current object, not the superclass.  So it simply calling the default implementation of respond_to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `super` does not mean check whether it respond to `T`'s super class, but just mean using the `respond_to` method extended from the `T`'s super class.

Because `T` has the instance method `t2`, so it will return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

super doesn't mean "forget you're an instance of T", it means call your superclass' implementation of `respond_to?`

That implementation isn't hard coded to check Object's method, it's a general implementation that goes over the object's ancestors checking for the existance of the method.

Comment: Yeah Object#respond_to? still checks if an instance of T responds to that method, not an instance of Object itself. I was not thinking clearly at first.